# Can the ICMP "pad" safely be stripped in most situations for defense?

Tags: icmp

I'm learning about data exfiltration using ICMP and delivery of a payload is generally done using the `-p` "pad bytes" in `ping -c 1 -p $encoded_payload`. Are there often legitimate use for "pad bytes"? Can it simply be stripped by a firewall in most cases?

Comment: To add something of potential value :) Why don't you just drop ICMP ping/pong? Many firewalls seems to, and while it's annoying when trying to diagnose network issues, it's probably less surprising than changed packets.

Comment: *Are there often legitimate use for "pad bytes"?*  - Android [ping](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/ping/+/27ca8cd5cb0891c8a15175b52c5c24253dea5b17/ping.c#637) uses it to include a timestamp for computing the round-trip time.

Comment: @domen While dropping ICMP is a great option, I'm looking into attacking & defending when certain ports & protocols are allowed, looking for ways to hide data in transit from people in the SOC & how to detect such things.